# How does the DownScale2x2 BasicPostProcess work in DirectX Tool Kit?

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12, directxtk

I have a DirectX 12 desktop project on Windows 11 that implements post-processing using a combination of DXTK post-process effects.

The aim of the post-proc sequence is to end up with individual bloom and blur textures (along with a depth texture rendered in a depth pass) which are sampled in a 'big triangle' pixel shader to achieve a depth of field effect for the final backbuffer screen image.

The DXTK PostProcesses operate on the full-size (1920x1080) screen texture. Presently this isn't impacting performance (benchmarked at 60fps), but I imagine it could be an issue when I eventually want to support 4K resolutions in future, where full-size image post-processing could be expensive.

Since the recommended best practice is to operate on a scaled down copy of the source image,
I hoped to achieve this by using half-size (i.e. quarter resolution) working textures with the *DownScale_2x2* **BasicPostProcess** option. But after several attempts experimenting with the effect, only the top-left quarter of the original source image is being rendered to the downsized texture... not the full image as expected per the documentation:

***DownScale_2x2:** Downscales each 2x2 block of pixels to an average. This is intended to write to a render target that is half the size of the source texture in each dimension.*

Other points of note:

- scene geometry is first rendered to a **_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT** MSAA render target and resolved to single-sample 16fp target
- postprocessing operates on resolved single-sample 16fp target (where only the intermediate 'Pass1' & 'Pass2' working render targets are set to half the backbuffer length & width)
- final processed image is tonemapped to the **_R10G10B10A2_UNORM** swapchain backbuffer for presentation.

The following code snippets show how I'm implementing the DownScale_2x2 shader into my post-process. Hopefully it's enough to resolve the issue and I can update with more info if necessary.

Resource initialization under *CreateDeviceDependentResources()*:

```
namespace GameConstants {
    constexpr DXGI_FORMAT BACKBUFFERFORMAT(DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM); // back buffer to support hdr rendering
    constexpr DXGI_FORMAT HDRFORMAT(DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT); // format for hdr render targets
    constexpr DXGI_FORMAT DEPTHFORMAT(DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT); // format for render target depth buffer
    constexpr UINT MSAACOUNT(4u); // requested multisample count
}

...

    //
    // Render targets
    //

    mMsaaHelper = std::make_unique<MSAAHelper>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT, GameConstants::DEPTHFORMAT, GameConstants::MSAACOUNT);
    mMsaaHelper->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    
    mDistortionRenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::BACKBUFFERFORMAT);
    mHdrRenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT);
    mPass1RenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT);
    mPass2RenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT);
    mBloomRenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT);
    mBlurRenderTex = std::make_unique<RenderTexture>(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT);
    
    mDistortionRenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    mHdrRenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    mPass1RenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    mPass2RenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    mBloomRenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    mBlurRenderTex->SetClearColor(GameConstants::CLEARCOLOR);
    
    mMsaaHelper->SetDevice(device); // Set the MSAA device. Note this updates GetSampleCount.
    
    mDistortionRenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::DistortionMaskSRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::DistortionMaskRTV));
    
    mHdrRenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::HdrSRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::HdrRTV));
    
    mPass1RenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::Pass1SRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::Pass1RTV));
    
    mPass2RenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::Pass2SRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::Pass2RTV));
    
    mBloomRenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::BloomSRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::BloomRTV));
    
    mBlurRenderTex->SetDevice(device,
        mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::BlurSRV),
        mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::BlurRTV));

...

    RenderTargetState ppState(GameConstants::HDRFORMAT, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN); // 2d postproc rendering

...

    // Set other postprocessing effects

    mBloomExtract = std::make_unique<BasicPostProcess>(device, ppState, BasicPostProcess::BloomExtract);
    mBloomPass = std::make_unique<BasicPostProcess>(device, ppState, BasicPostProcess::BloomBlur);
    mBloomCombine = std::make_unique<DualPostProcess>(device, ppState, DualPostProcess::BloomCombine);
    mGaussBlurPass = std::make_unique<BasicPostProcess>(device, ppState, BasicPostProcess::GaussianBlur_5x5);
    mDownScalePass = std::make_unique<BasicPostProcess>(device, ppState, BasicPostProcess::DownScale_2x2);
```

Resource resizing under *CreateWindowSizeDependentResources()*:

```
    // Get current backbuffer dimensions
    CD3DX12_RECT outputRect(mDeviceResources->GetOutputSize());

    // Determine the render target size in pixels
    mBackbufferSize.x = std::max<UINT>(outputRect.right - outputRect.left, 1u);
    mBackbufferSize.y = std::max<UINT>(outputRect.bottom - outputRect.top, 1u);

...

    mMsaaHelper->SetWindow(outputRect);

    XMUINT2 halfSize(mBackbufferSize.x / 2u, mBackbufferSize.y / 2u);

    mBloomRenderTex->SetWindow(outputRect);
    mBlurRenderTex->SetWindow(outputRect);
    mDistortionRenderTex->SetWindow(outputRect);
    mHdrRenderTex->SetWindow(outputRect);
    mPass1RenderTex->SizeResources(halfSize.x, halfSize.y);
    mPass2RenderTex->SizeResources(halfSize.x, halfSize.y);
```

Post-processing implementation:

```
mMsaaHelper->Prepare(commandList);
Clear(commandList);

// Render 3d scene

mMsaaHelper->Resolve(commandList, mHdrRenderTex->GetResource(),
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET);

//
// Postprocessing
//

// Set texture descriptor heap in prep for postprocessing if necessary.
// Unbind dsv for postprocess textures and sprites.

ID3D12DescriptorHeap* postProcHeap[] = { mPostProcSrvDescHeap->Heap() };
commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(UINT(std::size(postProcHeap)), postProcHeap);

// downscale pass

CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvDownScaleDescriptor(mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::Pass1RTV));
commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &rtvDownScaleDescriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

mPass1RenderTex->BeginScene(commandList);  // transition to render target state
mDownScalePass->SetSourceTexture(mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetGpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::HdrSRV), mHdrRenderTex->GetResource());
mDownScalePass->Process(commandList);
mPass1RenderTex->EndScene(commandList); // transition to pixel shader resource state

// blur horizontal pass

commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &rtvPass2Descriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

mPass2RenderTex->BeginScene(commandList); // transition to render target state
mGaussBlurPass->SetSourceTexture(mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetGpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::Pass1SRV), mPass1RenderTex->GetResource());
//mGaussBlurPass->SetSourceTexture(mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetGpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::HdrSRV), mHdrRenderTex->GetResource());
mGaussBlurPass->SetGaussianParameter(1.f);
mGaussBlurPass->SetBloomBlurParameters(TRUE, 4.f, 1.f); // horizontal blur
mGaussBlurPass->Process(commandList);
mPass2RenderTex->EndScene(commandList); // transition to pixel shader resource

// blur vertical pass

CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvBlurDescriptor(mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::BlurRTV));
commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &rtvBlurDescriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

mBlurRenderTex->BeginScene(commandList); // transition to render target state
mGaussBlurPass->SetSourceTexture(mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetGpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::Pass2SRV), mPass2RenderTex->GetResource());
mGaussBlurPass->SetBloomBlurParameters(FALSE, 4.f, 1.f); // vertical blur
mGaussBlurPass->Process(commandList);
mBlurRenderTex->EndScene(commandList); // transition to pixel shader resource

// render the final image to hdr texture

CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHdrDescriptor(mRtvDescHeap->GetCpuHandle(RTV_Descriptors::HdrRTV));
commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &rtvHdrDescriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

//mHdrRenderTex->BeginScene(commandList); // transition to render target state

commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(mRootSig.Get()); // bind root signature
commandList->SetPipelineState(mPsoDepthOfField.Get()); // set PSO
```

...

```
commandList->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(RootParameterIndex::PSDofCB, psDofCB.GpuAddress());
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::PostProcDT, mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetFirstGpuHandle());

// use the big triangle optimization to draw a fullscreen quad

commandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
commandList->DrawInstanced(3u, 1u, 0u, 0u);

...

PIXBeginEvent(commandList, PIX_COLOR_DEFAULT, L"Tone Map");
// Set swapchain backbuffer as the tonemapping render target and unbind depth/stencil for sprites (UI)

CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvDescriptor(mDeviceResources->GetRenderTargetView());
commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &rtvDescriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE postProcTexture(mPostProcSrvDescHeap->GetGpuHandle(SRV_PostProcDescriptors::HdrSRV));
ApplyToneMapping(commandList, postProcTexture);
```

Vertex shader:

```
/*

    We use the 'big triangle' optimization that only requires three vertices to completely
    cover the full screen area.

    v0    v1        ID    NDC     UV
    *____*          --  -------  ----
    | | /           0   (-1,+1)  (0,0)
    |_|/            1   (+3,+1)  (2,0)
    | /             2   (-1,-3)  (0,2)
    |/
    *
    v2

*/

TexCoordVertexOut VS(uint id : SV_VertexID)
{
    TexCoordVertexOut vout;

    vout.texCoord = float2((id << 1u) & 2u, id & 2u);

    // See Luna p.687
    float x =  vout.texCoord.x * 2.f - 1.f;
    float y = -vout.texCoord.y * 2.f + 1.f;

    // Procedurally generate each NDC vertex.
    // The big triangle produces a quad covering the screen in NDC space.
    vout.posH = float4(x, y, 0.f, 1.f);

    // Transform quad corners to view space near plane.
    float4 ph = mul(vout.posH, InvProj);
    vout.posV = ph.xyz / ph.w;

    return vout;
}
```

Pixel shader:

```
float4 PS(TexCoordVertexOut pin) : SV_TARGET
//float4 PS(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : SV_TARGET
{

...

    // Get downscale texture sample
    float3 colorDownScale = Pass1Tex.Sample(PointSampler, pin.texCoord).rgb;

...

    return float4(colorDownScale, 1.f); // only top-quarter of source input is rendered!
    //return float4(colorOutput, 1.f);
    //return float4(distortCoords, 0.f, 1.f);
    //return float4(colorHDR, 1.f);
    //return float4(colorBlurred, 1.f);
    //return float4(colorBloom, 1.f);
    //return float4((p.z * 0.01f).rrr, 1.f); // multiply by a contrast factor
}
```

Comment: "only the top-left quarter of the original source image is being rendered to the downsized texture" have you changed viewport and scissor accordingly?

Comment: @mateeeeeee, I'd be surprised if viewport or scissor rectangle settings were involved. I'm using DXTK **RenderTexture** objects for all offscreen render targets and I haven't seen any documentation referring to changing viewport and scissor rect.

Comment: The **RenderTexture** class implements `SetWindow()` and `SizeResources()` methods only for setting texture dimensions. No method for `SetViewport()` exists as such...

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with ToolKit and Chuck Walbourn will know more, but you can try setting the viewport and scissor rect with half size values yourself and see if it makes any difference. Don't forget to restore old values after.

Comment: Yes I'm hoping for a reply from Chuck. I also hope more people adopt the Tool Kit for DirectX development... it's such a great library and basically essential for indie DX12 developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PostProcess` class uses a 'full-screen quad' rendering model. Since we can rely on Direct3D 10.0 or later class hardware, it makes use of the 'self-generating quad' model to avoid the need for a VB.

As such, the self-generating quad is going to be positioned wherever you have the viewport set. The scissors settings are also needed since it uses the "big-triangle" optimization to avoid having a diagonal seam across the image IF you have the viewport positioned anywhere except the full render target.

I have this detail in the [Writing custom shaders](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Writing-custom-shaders) tutorial, but I forgot to replicate it in the PostProcess docs on the wiki.

**TL;DR:** When you go to render to the smaller render target, use:

```
auto vp = m_deviceResources->GetScreenViewport();

Viewport halfvp(vp);
halfvp.height /= 2.f;
halfvp.width /= 2.f;
commandList->RSSetViewports(1, halfvp.Get12());
```

Then when we switch back to your full-size rendertarget, use:

```
commandList->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
```

Updated the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/PostProcess) page.

Comment: Thanks @ChuckWalbourn, modifying the viewport between passes did the trick! There's just one more thing I can't work out. So I'm first rendering the scene to an MSAA target and resolving to the HDR target, where I set the Resolve() to return the HDR resource in 'render target' state. Then the resource is sent to the downscale pass WITHOUT explicitly transitioning to 'pixel shader resource' state. But instead of barking at me, the code compiles without issue! It feels like I'm getting away with something... am I getting a "free lunch" here, or is **BasicPostProcess** handling the transition?

Comment: For Windows there are some complex 'Common state promotion and decay sample' rules that might be triggering here for the state transitions. I don't rely on them personally since they are not on by default for Xbox. Try running with the debug layer on and make sure you don't see any warnings.

Comment: Hi @Chuck, I can confirm the debug layer is also happy. It's painful when there are warnings, since they're generated for every frame of application debug runtime. So you quit your apparently bug-free app only to be confronted by thousands of lines of identical warning messages! I learned a little about common state promotion/decay while reading Frank Luna's _Intro to DX12_ text, where I updated his examples by replacing **D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON** flags with (for example) **D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST** during resource creation, to save a line of code 'promoting' the resource later on.

Comment: I also note the _DownScale_2x2_ shader isn't strictly necessary in the blurring postprocess, but a neat trick is to downscale to a _Pass1_ texture, and then wrap the _Pass1->Pass2_ sequence in a for-loop. That way you can execute the loop for the desired number of blurs. I find a texture blurred between 2-4 times, when lerped (based on linear scene depth) with the 'sharp' original scene, provides awesome depth of field.

Comment: After reviewing the documentation, it looks like using **BasicPostProcess** in _Copy_ mode is better in this use case, since a 'perfect pixel average' isn't necessary when downsizing to the blur passes. I've tested this out to find no degradation in quality in the final DoF effect. Also as stated in _**Remarks**_, would the comment that "this can also be used to achieve GPU-based texture resizing as well" imply an additional efficiency gain in using the _Copy_ shader?